# Linux, can I redirect the debug output of a external library (.so)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging, console

I'm developing an app in qt c++, on linux (and then others platforms).
I'm using a library of third part in my project. During the program execution the library writes debug messages on my debug console and I need to keep clean it for debug others part of the program.
What can I do to redirect (or hide) only the debug messages from this library? 
Thanks

Regards 
Andrea

Comment: Assuming you are using QT Creator, just use the debugging window. It will show you everything without the need for printing to debug

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes, I use the debugging window but I don't want to see the debug information from this third part library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `qInstallMsgHandler` and create a custom message handler.

Unfortunately this way means that all qDebug messages get handled the same way, regardless from where. It does, however give you the flexibility to create your own debug message type and use that in your application, whereas the shared library uses the plain qDebug type.

This is modified code from a Qt example:

```
    #include <qapplication.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    const unsigned int MyMsgType = QtFatalMsg + 1;

    void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
    {
        switch (type) {
        case QtDebugMsg:
            // do nothing.
            break;
        case QtWarningMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
            abort();
        case MyMsgType:
            fprintf(stderr, "MyMsg: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        return app.exec();
    }
```

Elsewhere to print your custom debug message use `QDebug(MyMsgType) << "Message.";`

Comment: Thanks it's a good idea, but I think that this stuff use the same window to output, and I need that the window keeps clean because I've to analyze a lot of things throw debug.

Comment: @Andrea993 you can do what you want to the QtDebugMsg type. You can have it go to ether if you want. That would definitely keep the debug console clean.  I will modify the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't see that there is "QML/JS console" that allow to filter messages. I saw only "Application ouptut"

Answer (score 1):

If you have the code of the *.so you can try compile it in release mode, that way you avoid debug messages from being compiled/executed.

You can still use the "release mode" library with your "debug mode" project. Note you don´t be able to see any symbols from the library neither.

In reponse to your comment:

> *... I've already tryed but the library keeps to print debug messages also in release build*

It seems that messages you see aren´t really "debug" messages. It is possible the messages are printed by `cout` or `printf`? Is that the case, I'm afraid you can't redirect just the library's messages.

You can redirect messages of a process, and when you load a library, every function you execute is executed by the loader process, hence, it would be as redirect/hide just part of the output of the process.

But, since you have the code, why don't add the

```
#ifdef DEBUG
...
#endif
```

blocks your self?

Comment: unfortunately I've already tryed but the library keeps to print debug messages also in release build.

Comment: I didn't want to modify the library source because is LGPL and then I have to upload the changes, but if it is the only way I think I will do it.